# Can't extract and associate name with latitude and longitude data

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have 15 LI items on a page, and I am trying to reconstruct the data from the heavily nested html to a simple JSON object with name, latitude and longitude.

For example, one record could look like:

`{name: "Pied a Terre", lat: "51.5191", "lng: "-0.1399435"}`

This is a slightly simplified version of the each LI in the HTML I'm working with:

```
<li class="has-distance link-block" itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">

    <meta content="Yes" itemprop="acceptsReservations">

    <div class="item" data-id="109054" data-weight="-42.4101">

        <img class="photo loaded" src="http://img.static-bookatable.com/heeltap-london-bridge-london-1.jpg?id=218ab1c679b5a543c0a6b53012c379d5.jpg=" width="140" height="100" alt="Heeltap - London">        

    <div class="detail">

        <span itemprop="reviews" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <meta content="0" itemprop="ratingValue">
            <meta content="0" itemprop="reviewCount">
            <span class="star rating" title="Not yet rated">
                <span class="average"><span>*****</span></span>
            </span>
        </span>

        <h3 class="fn" itemprop="name">Heeltap</h3>
        <p class="adr wide" itemprop="address">Chaucer House, White Hart Yard, London, SE1 1NX</p>
        <p class="cuisine" itemprop="servesCuisine">British </p>
        <span itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
            <meta content="51.50418" itemprop="latitude">
            <meta content="-0.08918" itemprop="longitude">
        </span>

    </div> <!-- detail end tag -->

</div> <!-- item end tag -->

<a class="block-link" data-analytics="Restaurant List|Restaurant Click|offpage" href="heeltap-london-bridge-london" itemprop="url" title="Heeltap (Not yet rated)">Heeltap</a>

</li>
```

This is the latest code I've tried (out of many, many different attempts):

(I refactored it previously storing the long jQuery selector in variable, and using $(this), but I thought this could be affecting the code so I did it in a straightforward but verbose manner below):

```
$('.has-distance').each(function(){

    var obj = {};

    obj["name"] = $(this).find('.block-link').html();

    // console.log(nameObject);

    // $('.has-distance').find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().each(function(){

        if ( $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('itemprop') === "latitude" ) {
         obj["lat"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('content');
       }
        else if ( $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('itemprop') === "longitude" ) {
        obj["lng"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('content');
      }

      console.log(obj);

  });
```

Unfortunately the console log only returns the below, and refuses to also extract the longitude and put it in the object (even though when I do it as a separate .each function the if / else if logic works).

```
Object {name: "Momo", lat: "51.5112371"}
Object {name: "Pied a Terre", lat: "51.5191"}
Object {name: "Crazy Bear - Fitzrovia", lat: "51.5196971"}
Object {name: "Les Deux Salons", lat: "51.5094799"}
Object {name: "The National Café", lat: "51.508929"}
Object {name: "Athenaeum", lat: "51.50464"}
Object {name: "inamo", lat: "51.5149166"}
Object {name: "The Grill at The Dorchester", lat: "51.50729"}
Object {name: "Planet Hollywood London", lat: "51.5092777"}
Object {name: "The Ritz Restaurant - London", lat: "51.50718"}
Object {name: "Homage Restaurant at The Waldorf Hilton", lat: "51.5121546"}
Object {name: "DSTRKT Restaurant and Bar", lat: "51.5110772"}
Object {name: "Marconi Lounge at ME London", lat: "51.51163"}
Object {name: "Kaspar's Seafood Bar and Grill", lat: "51.510012"}
Object {name: "Hakkasan - Hanway Place", lat: "51.5169686"}
```

Please help, I'm really stuck here! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if ($(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"] meta[itemprop="latitude"]').length > 0) {
    obj["lat"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"] meta[itemprop="latitude"]').attr('content');
}
if ( $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"] meta[itemprop="longitude"]').length > 0) {
    obj["lng"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"] meta[itemprop="longitude"]').attr('content');
}
```

Or you can do it with $.each loop

```
  $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('itemprop') === "latitude" ) {
        obj["lat"] = $(this).attr('content');
    } else if ( $(this).attr('itemprop') === "longitude" ) {
        obj["lng"] = $(this).attr('content');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ranish, both of these work, the second one is more concise, so I think I'm going with that, seems very similar to what I had in a previous iteration. Is one more efficient at running than the other? This is the full code together with the name extraction: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/23d6232f52cf688d18375668e13dc32c

Comment: I think both will be equal in terms of efficiency, might be slight difference but that can be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the conditionals if you put them in the selector:

```
$('.has-distance').each(function() {
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = $(this).find('.block-link').html();
  obj.lat = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children('meta[itemprop="latitude"]').attr('content');
  obj.lng = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children('meta[itemprop="longitude"]').attr('content');
  console.log(obj);
});
```

alternately:

```
$('.has-distance').each(function() {
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = $(this).find('.block-link').html();
  var geo = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]');
  obj.lat = geo.children('meta[itemprop="latitude"]').attr('content');
  obj.lng = geo.children('meta[itemprop="longitude"]').attr('content');
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The sections of your code that extract latitude and longitude are separate branches of an if/else statement, which means *only one of them will run* for each element matched by the '.has-distance' jQuery selector.  If you must test for the existence of the values first, you could just use separate if statements:

```
$('.has-distance').each(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj["name"] = $(this).find('.block-link').html();

    if ( $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('itemprop') === "latitude" ) {
        obj["lat"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('content');
    }
    if ( $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('itemprop') === "longitude" ) {
        obj["lng"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().attr('content');
    }
    console.log(obj);
  });
```

Though, as noted in my comment below, children().attr() does not iterate through the children automatically.  From the [jQuery docs on .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

So you'll have to iterate through them somehow.  You could use .each():

```
$('.has-distance').each(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj["name"] = $(this).find('.block-link').html();

    $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"]').children().each(function() {
        if( $(this).attr('itemprop') === "latitude" ) {
            obj["lat"] = $(this).attr('content');
        }
        else if ( $(this).attr('itemprop') === "longitude" ) {
            obj["lng"] = $(this).attr('content');
        }
    });

    console.log(obj);
});
```

Or if you *know* the structure of the data you're parsing, and you only need a few elements rather than hundreds, you could get rid of the if statement(s) and the nested each() and use something simpler like this:

```
$('.has-distance').each(function(){
  var obj = {};

  obj["name"] = $(this).find('.block-link').html();
  obj["lat"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"] > meta[itemprop="latitude"]').attr('content');
  obj["lng"] = $(this).find('span[itemprop="geo"] > meta[itemprop="longitude"]').attr('content');

  console.log(obj);
});
```

You might also consider changing how you collect the "name" attribute for your object to something more appropriate:

```
obj["name"] = $(this).find('[itemprop="name"]').html();
```

Comment: I tried doing separate if statements before and it didn't work. This doesn't work either in console, only prints out 'lat', like before. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Or, is there any other way I can do it without doing if / else?

Comment: Ah, I think the issue is that children().attr() does not iterate through all children.  From the attr() documentation:  "Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element."